# Master cannot be upgraded to "1.15.9-gke.24" in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We have the version 1.12.10-gke.22 of kubernetes master, but we needed change to a 1.15.9-gke.24.

We running the command to clusters upgrade :

```
gcloud container clusters upgrade  <cluster-name> --master --cluster-version 1.15.9-gke.24 --zone us-central1-c
```

And we receive the response:

```
Master cannot be upgraded to "1.15.9-gke.24": cannot upgrade the master more than a minor version at a time.
```

In Google Cloud Platform console, we have the message:

[image]

Any ideas or solutions? Thanks

Comment: After show up the 1.13 version, the upgrade was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of our customers experienced the same error. They cannot upgrade from 1.12.10-gke.22 because the 1.13 upgrade is not available.

The fix is in the works currently. Meanwhile to workaround the issue you can create a cluster with master version 1.15.9-gke.24 and migrate your workloads from the old cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are waiting for fix.

Comment: Hi Erhard, the 1.13 version is available! Ty

Comment: Do you know where this is being discussed? Thanks.

Comment: It was discussed internally, but I left Google recently so I cannot help you. Try searching on public sites or create a support ticket. Good luck!